# Change div class based on Request[]

Tags: c#, asp.net

The Title might not be specific enough, but I'm asking here because I have no idea how to search on my issue or make a short description of it.

My issue is that i got several div's with the same class but different ID's, when clicking on one of them the page url changes from "url" to "url?page=one", which changes the content by Request["page"], the content is from an array where i only show the ones fitting the request.

The thing i would like to do, is to "access" the div with the same ID as the Request["page"]. But i have no idea how to do it.

i think it would be something like:

```
          if(div.id == Request["page"]){ do this }
```

That's the kind of solution i'm looking for (if possible), just a working one.

i hope someone is able to help.

I might be able to obtain the same result with a lot of clumsy code, but i would like to learn and make better code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to change your Divs to be `<asp:Panel` with `runat="server"` attribute so you can interact with it in the codebehind. These will be rendered into Divs;

```
 <asp:Panel ID="pageOnePanel" runat="server">
     foo
 </asp:Panel>
```

Will be rendered as (the Id maybe rendered differently but that's a whole other story):

```
 <div id="pageOnePanel">
     foo
 </div>
```

Now you can approach this in many ways but here are two, this is the more fixed route:

```
Protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string pageName = Request.QueryString["page"]; //expecting "PageOne" or "PageTwo"
    switch(pageName)
    {
        case("pageOne"):
            pageOnePanel.CssClass = "myClass";
            break;
        case("pageTwo"):
            pageTwoPanel.CssClass = "myClass";
            break;
        default:
            defaultPanel.CssClass = "myClass";
            break;
    }
}
```

And this is the more dynamic, this one needs more checks in because if the page attribute doesn't match you're going to get errors. This code is the bare minimum for it:

```
Protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string pageName = Request.QueryString["page"]; //expecting "PageOne" or "PageTwo"
    Panel myPanel = (Panel)FindControl(pageName + "Panel");
    myPanel.CssClass = "myClass";   
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! the switch is a perfect way to do it